# Module Window wont open when I select 'View'

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this window Module to open however Its not picking up the #openModel Reference.
The URL changes to index.php?page=TestOverview#openModal but nothing appears

See screenshot of the user interface below:
[image]

Ultimalty I want to be able to drop colapse one of my Headers which display the table and when a user clicks on 'View' It should bring up the module and display addtional information for the user to see.

HTML

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrap-table100">
    <div class="table100 ver1 m-b-110">
      <table data-vertable="ver1">
        <thead>
          <thead>
            <tr class="row100 head">
              <th class="column100 column1">Test Number</th>
              <th class="column100 column2">Test Module</th>
              <th class="column100 column3">Class Average</th>
              <th class="column100 column3">More Info</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = $data1->fetch()): ?>
            <tr class="row100">
              <td class="column100 column1">
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['TEST_ID']) ?>
              </td>
              <td class="column100 column2">
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['TEST_DESCRIPTION']); ?>
              </td>
              <td class="column100 column3">
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['TEST_AVERAGE']); ?>
              </td>
              <td class="column100 column4"><a href=""><a href="#openModal">View</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
              <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                <div>
                  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                  <h2>TEST INFORMTATION</h2>
                  <p>DISPLAY MORE INFO ON STUDENTS - LINE 2</p>
                  <p>DISPLAY MORE INFO ON STUDENTS - LINE 2</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: created a code snippet based on the code you have provided. Can you please explain what is the issue?

Comment: Well Its diplaying in the snippet :/ 
But not on my page.... 

@XenioGracias

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pointing to what's inside the modal (openModal) rather than the modal itself (myModal).

Also, you need to add 'data-toggle="modal"' to the href if you want to trigger the modal without using Javascript.

Change:

```
<a href="#openModal">View</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">View</a>
```